# Редактирование входных элементов в функцию

Tags: c, функции, макросы

Можно ли с помощью макроса изменить аргументы входящие в функцию? Например:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define G(T) _Generic((T), void *: 0, int: 1, const char *: 2, double: 3)

int test (void *, ...);

int main ()
{
    test(G(1), G(4.00), G("Hello world"));

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли сделать так, что бы в `test` передовалось

```
test(1, 4.00, "Hello world");
```

и он автоматически применял макрос `G` ко всем аргументам, или это бред?

Comment: Вы подобным образом на самом деле хотите передать в `test(...)` только типы аргументов (в виде целых литералов, как у вас написан макрос `G(T)`) или все же пары -- тип-значение?

Comment: Лучше напишите что вы в целом хотите сделать?

Comment: @avp Пары тип-значение, я собираюсь создать словарь, а сама задумка заключается в том что я передаю в функцию через запятую элементы с разными типами данных, которые преобразуются в одну структуру.

Comment: Тогда вам нужен чуть другой макрос, скажем, `#define A(x)  G(x), x`, который раскрывается в пару аргументов при использовании в списке аргументов вызова `test(A(1), A(4.0), A("Hello"))`

Comment: @avp Спасибо вам за совет, пойду пробовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Единственное, что можно сделать — это что-то типа

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define G(T) _Generic((T), void *: 0, int: 1, const char *: 2, double: 3)

void
test(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

#define PRINT(x) (printf("%i\n", (int) G(va_arg(args, x))))

    for (; *fmt; ++fmt) {
        if (*fmt == 'v')
            PRINT(void *);
        else if (*fmt == 'i')
            PRINT(int);
        else if (*fmt == 'c')
            PRINT(const char *);
        else if (*fmt == 'd')
            PRINT(double);
    }

#undef PRINT

    va_end(args);
}

int
main(void)
{
    test("vcid", (void *) 1, (const char *) "hello", 13, 3.14); 
}
```

Т. е. вам в любом  случае придется как-то передавать в функцию информацию о типе каждого параметра, чтобы «вытащить» значение этого параметра через `va_arg`.

---

Если вы хотите сделать «словарь», значения которого могут иметь разный тип и будут задаваться одной функцией-конструктуром, то можно сделать что-то типа такого:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum types {
    TYPE_POINTER_TO_VOID,
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_POINTER_TO_CONST_CHAR,
    TYPE_DOUBLE
};

typedef struct {
    enum types type;

    union {
        void *value_of_type_pointer_to_void;
        int value_of_type_int;
        const char *value_of_type_pointer_to_const_char;
        double value_of_type_double;
    };
} dict_entry_t;

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    dict_entry_t entries[];
} dict_t;

dict_t *create_dict(const char *, ...);

int
main(void)
{
    dict_t *d = create_dict("vcid", (void *) NULL, (const char *) "hello", 13, 3.14);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < d->size; ++i) {
        dict_entry_t *e = &d->entries[i];

        if (e->type == TYPE_POINTER_TO_VOID)
            printf("%p\n", e->value_of_type_pointer_to_void);
        else if (e->type == TYPE_INT)
            printf("%i\n", e->value_of_type_int);
        else if (e->type == TYPE_POINTER_TO_CONST_CHAR)
            printf("%s\n", e->value_of_type_pointer_to_const_char);
        else if (e->type == TYPE_DOUBLE)
            printf("%f\n", e->value_of_type_double);
    }

    free(d);
}

#define G(T) _Generic((T),                    \
    void *: TYPE_POINTER_TO_VOID,             \
    int: TYPE_INT,                            \
    const char *: TYPE_POINTER_TO_CONST_CHAR, \
    double: TYPE_DOUBLE                       \
)

#define ADD(member, T)            \
do {                              \
    e->type = G(e->member);       \
    e->member = va_arg(args, T);  \
} while (0)

dict_t *
create_dict(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    dict_t *dict = malloc(sizeof(*dict) + sizeof(dict_entry_t) * strlen(fmt));
    dict->size = strlen(fmt);

    for (size_t i = 0; fmt[i]; ++i) {
        dict_entry_t *e = &dict->entries[i];

        if (fmt[i] == 'v')
            ADD(value_of_type_pointer_to_void, void *);
        else if (fmt[i] == 'i')
            ADD(value_of_type_int, int);
        else if (fmt[i] == 'c')
            ADD(value_of_type_pointer_to_const_char, const char *);
        else if (fmt[i] == 'd')
            ADD(value_of_type_double, double);
    }

    return dict;
}

#undef G
#undef ADD
```

Comment: Из текста вопроса мне кажется, что автор хотел как-то использовать `G()` в main при вызове `test(...)`, а не внутри ее.  А PRINT сформатом "%i" для `char *` вообще как-то странно выглядит

Comment: @avp, хм... а где там `%i` для `char *`? Я что-то не вижу.

Comment: В макросе `PRINT(x)` формат `"%i\n"` действует для всех `x`

Comment: @avp, так печатаем мы выражения, выбранные дженериком — 0, 1, 2 и 3.

Comment: Лучше сделайте `create_dict(...)` как функцию, которая получает список пар, *завершающийся* типом, который означает конец списка. Тогда необходимость в первом аргументе, который может быть unconsistent с элементами списка отпадет.

Comment: @avp, в этом коде многое стоит поменять, это я так, для демонстрации идеи  :)

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @Gari, спасибо за интересный вопрос.